# Locating OBDI2 port on used vehicle ( Mitsubishi L200 year: 1998 )

Tags: obd-ii, mitsubishi

**Vehicle**

model: L200
Make: Mitsubishi
year: 1998 ( engine ~2004 from swap )

I am located in the carribean, finding solid used vehicles is a challenge actually that an understatement. Vehicles are imported from US or Asia that may have been used and abused and sold cheap then sold 200- 300% higher here. As a result people will stick to Japanese brands as they hold their weight and are easier to find parts for.

Anyways, my issue I want to locate the OBDI2 port on my truck this is usually a no brainer task and takes thirty seconds. I want to find the OBDI2 port for many reasons .. I am having a hard time cause I found what looks to be (2) ports which doesnt seem right. They also to make things more confusing have a bundle of mess or wires above and on top of that they have what appear to be impossible covers to get off.. can someone please confirm this for me, thank you

[image: for looks]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The OBDII should not be either of the plugs you're showing in your images ... at least they do not look like them to me. You are looking in the correct area. The only thing I can think of is something is plugged into the port, which is obscuring it. If it isn't just to the right of the hood pull, then it's probably hanging free somewhere. It should be mounted, though.

Comment: what does it look like under the protective cover shown in the last photo?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the vehicle does have a GPS as I am making payments and thats custom in this country... could they potentially be using the OBDI2 port to power the GPS ? what are these ports then? I have never seen them

Comment: @fred_dot_u there is nothing under there just speaker wires and a few other wires that are not for the port

Comment: If you could show me the back side of both of those connectors? Where the wires go in ... I'm wondering if one of them is actually the OBDII port with something plugged into it (which could be your GPS stuff).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 sorry, the backside as in you want to see how the wires insert into the plastic cradle of that port in question?

Comment: Yes, please. If the black part is the front (where your finger is at), I'd like to see the opposite side where the wires go in. From what I can see, it appears to be white in the one picture. I can't tell what the 2nd connector looks like (the one you're not showing in close up).

Comment: Unfortunately, neither one of those are OBDII DLCs. You did well with your camera, so no worries. Because we have a limit of how many comments which can be on any post (20) before there are "repercussions", I'm going to delete some of these. Thank you for taking the time to get the pic and video, but we need to look elsewhere to find your OBDII port.

Comment: Are the photos at the bottom of this page like your vehicle? - https://www.outilsobdfacile.com/location-plug-connector-obd/Mitsubishi-l200-3

Comment: @HandyHowie - If you look at the OP's 2nd picture, this is an upward view of the area shown in the pictures on the site you provided. There's no port sticking out there. It would be present at the right side of the image if it were. I saw those images when I did my search, but didn't think they were detailed enough to really get a good understanding of where *exactly* to look.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure, this could actually be your OBDII port. Secondarily, with this being a 1998 model, if it came from Europe, it might not have an OBDII port ... this might be an OBDI port instead (looks possible from the partial view). Europe didn't mandate an OBDII setup until 2002, IIRC.

[image]

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow again I feel this is a cover but it's so difficult to get off and squeezing or prying doesn't seem to get me far , i'll go for it and be a bit more aggressive with decoupling the proposed peice

Comment: @Invic18 - The two ports you showed wiring for are not OBDII wiring. They are too big and too many. OBDII ports usually have like 5 to 7 wires, and are of smaller gauge (approx 20-24AWG). The ones at the back of what you are showing look to be 12-14AWG. I think taking these apart may cause you issues.

Comment: thank you, I have not touched them yet. only lightly but did not disturb anything. Through the control button hole for asseosories I can see the GPS it seems and i think although not 100% that it's connected to the target port. I have a friend with the same truck I am going to take a look at his since it def does not have a GPS installed.

Comment: Another place you can look is under the hood. Some manufacturers put their DLC port there on the firewall. I've seen it on the opposite side of the steering wheel. This was pretty much only on OBDI vehicles, though, because part of the OBDII spec was for the port to be located under the steering wheel along the knee panel somewhere. This was specified so people could find the ports easier.

Comment: Really hope I can find it eventually. I have a stage 1 chip I carefully picked for that Diesel.

Comment: "Usually, an OBD GPS tracker device draws power from the OBD port itself and contains a built-in antenna along with a GPS module in order to receive the GPS signal. In addition, OBD trackers communicate with the different vehicle subsystems for receiving vehicle diagnostic and fuel consumption related" since they wanted to hide the GPS during installation this would make sense. For them to cut wires and risk issues with the vehicle or shorting something; it seems likely they would use the OBDII port - although it's a giveaway for someone who has the intent to remove the GPS if they dishonest

Comment: @Invic18 - Agreed.